# Why is "h" of "-ham" dropped in English place names?

Tags: phonology, proper-nouns, toponomastics

In English, "h" in suffix "-ham" (originated from Old English "home") are skipped when pronouncing so "-ham" sound like "-am". Examples are "Fulham", "Tottenham" etc etc.

My question is what causes such phenomenon? Are there other consonants behave similarly? And finally when did this happen? On one hand it seems that this happened only recently as American English still read out the "h", while on the other hand "Tottenham" was spelled as "Totnam" as early as 16th century.

Comment: The status of English /h/ has changed since Middle English. Now /h/ occurs strictly before vowels, and constitutes a simple voiceless vocal onset, which is especially difficult to pronounce and to distinguish after consonants. In general, lightly pronounced sounds like [h] are especially prone to get lost, or to alternate with or to mutate into other fricatives, in all the languages of the world; look at "silent H" in Spanish or French, for instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is simply a reduction of the common, unstressed element: the vowel is centralised, and the initial /h/ is lost. (Note that there are few English words with /h/ after a consonant, and apart from names they are virtually all compounds like *offhand* and *uphill*).

A similar case is the /w/ in *-wich* and *-wick*, which in many place-names (but not all) has disappeared: *Greenwich*, *Harwich*, *Hawick*, *Alnwick*. Also compare the usual pronunciation of *-cester* as /stə/.

Where the 'h' of *-ham* follows 's' or 't', many places have a spelling pronunciation: *Chesham*, *Lewisham*, with /ʃ/; *Grantham*, with /θ/. I believe that these pronunciations are quite recent: I remember somebody from Chesham telling me forty years ago that locals said /'tʃɛzəm/.

Comment: Interesting. There's a locality called Chesham in Bury, Greater Manchester, and I've only ever heard it called /'tʃɛzəm/ (having lived within a mile for well over a decade).

Comment: Are you sure it was with [z] and not [s] before?

Comment: having grown up near Chesham (in Bucks) in the noughties, I was told that /'tʃɛsəm/ was the older pronunciation, and there were still occasional people who insisted that was the correct pronunciation, but it's pretty much completely been displaced by the spelling pronunciation

Comment: I now live near Masham, and to locals its always /-səm/. We can usually tell visitors because most of thm say /-ʃəm/.